# jQuery error: too much recursion

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, watermark

I'm using this [watermark plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/) for jQuery. It works fine on every page except for my registration where it gets called 4 times.  On the registration page I am getting a too much recursion error on line 57 of jQuery (one hosted on Google).  I don't think it's jQuery that is the problem, though I think it has to do with my code or that plugin.  Can you look to see if you see anything?

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".text").addClass("idleField");
    $(".text").focus(function(){
        $(this).removeClass("idleField");
        $(this).addClass("focusField");
    });
    $(".text").blur(function(){
        $(this).removeClass("focusField");
        $(this).addClass("idleField");
    });
    $("#recaptcha_response_field").attr("tabindex","5");
    <?php if(!is_ie()){ ?>
    $("#username").watermark("Desired Username");
    $("#password").watermark("Password between 6 and 12 characters");
    $("#confirmPassword").watermark("Confirm Password");
    $("#email").watermark("Please insert a valid email");
    <?php } ?>
    $("#checkUser").click(function(){
           $("#results").html("<img src='images/loading.gif' alt='loading...' />loading...");
        var user = $("#username").attr("value");
        $.get("library/regUserCheck.php", {name: user}, function(data){
            $("#results").html(data);
        });
    });
    <?php if($error){ //Make error fade out ?>
           $("#errorField").delay(5000).fadeOut(1250);
    <?php } ?>
});
```

Comment: What version of JQuery are you using? What link are you using to the Google JQuery CDN?

Comment: 1.4.4 https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js

Comment: @jeffan24 Could you change to the non-minified one and see what line the error occurs on?

Comment: Comment out all the lines and uncomment them one-at-a-time to see when it pukes.

Comment: @lonesomeday too much recursion
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.js
Line 1891

Comment: @n8wrl I did what you said it craps out on the watermarks.  It doesn't matter which one I do they all make it throw that error.  What I don't understand is that this only happens in IE and Firefox. In safari, opera and chrome it works great no problems at all.

Comment: Do you get a `TooMuchRecursionException` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too much recursion in your code, doesn't that mean anything for you? Here's the improved code:

```
$(function() {
    $(".text").addClass("idleField").focus(function () {
        $(this).removeClass("idleField").addClass("focusField");
    }).blur(function () {
        $(this).removeClass("focusField").addClass("idleField");
    });

    $("#recaptcha_response_field").attr("tabindex", "5");
    /*@cc_on
    var $username = $("#username");
    $username.watermark("Desired Username");
    $("#password").watermark("Password between 6 and 12 characters");
    $("#confirmPassword").watermark("Confirm Password");
    $("#email").watermark("Please insert a valid email");
    */
    $("#checkUser").click(function () {
        $("#results").html("<img src='images/loading.gif' alt='loading...' />loading...").load("library/regUserCheck.php", {
            name: $username.val()
        });
    });
    <?php if ($error) { /* Make error fade out */ ?>
        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#errorField").fadeOut(1250);
        }, 5000);
    <?php } ?>
});
```

Tips:

- You can use conditional comments (`/*@cc_on … */`) to handle IE, no need to do that with PHP.
- Never use a jQuery selector multiple times. jQuery needs to find that element in DOM multiple times. In most cases, you can use **chaining**, like this:

```
$('#el').click(function() {
    …
}).addClass('myClass');
```

If you can't do that, **cache** it to a variable. Example:

```
var $el = $('#el');
$el.html('loading…');
setTimeout(function() {
    $el.load('/ajax/echo/html', {html: 'Hello, world!'});
}, 5000);
```

For example, if you want to specify more CSS rules for an element, this is the best syntax:

```
$('#el').css({
    'background-color': 'blue',
    color: 'white'
});
```

- This really depends on style and isn't important, but you can use `$(function() {` as a shorthand for `$(document).ready(function() {`.

I hope that's enough. :)

Comment: I thought recursion meant it was getting stuck in a loop.  But thanks for that other stuff I really appreciate it, I'll let you know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is calling `watermark` multiple times I would try using timer:

```
$("#username").watermark("Desired Username");
window.setTimeout(function() { $("#password").watermark("Password between 6 and 12 characters"); }, 100);
window.setTimeout(function() { $("#confirmPassword").watermark("Confirm Password"); }, 200);
window.setTimeout(function() { $("#email").watermark("Please insert a valid email"); }, 300);
```